# HackerRank itertools.combinations()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving the following [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/itertools-combinations/problem) on HackerRank.

Here's my solution -

```
from itertools import combinations
a = input()
ls = list(map(str, a.split()))
for i in range(1, int(ls[1])+1):
    ls2 = []
    ls2 = list(map("".join, combinations(ls[0], i)))
    for elem in ls2:
        ls2[ls2.index(elem)] = "".join(sorted(elem))
    ls2.sort()
    for char in ls2:
        print(char)
```

But I feel it's not very efficient as it uses 2 Lists and 2 nested loops.

Any suggestions as to how can I improve the code?

Comment: In my experience, you should always avoid explicit loops when looking for performance. So that's never a bad first step.

Comment: Understood thanks @Juho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice solution, these are my suggestions:

- **Parsing the input**: in Python 3 the function `input` always returns a string, so the mapping can be removed. In Python 2, you can use `raw_input`.
- **Naming**: `ls` is too generic. In this case, a suggestion is to take the names from the problem description. From:

  ```
  a = input()
  ls = list(map(str, a.split()))
  ```

  To:

  ```
  S, k = input().split()
  ```
- **Sort in advance**: the problem requires to output the combinations in lexicographic sorted order. The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) says:

> The combination tuples are emitted in lexicographic ordering according
> to the order of the input iterable. So, if the input iterable is
> sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

So, instead of sorting each combination, it's enough sorting the input `S` at the beginning and all the combinations will be automatically sorted.

- **Use the output of** `itertools.combinations`: the output of `itertools.combinations` is an iterable or tuples, which can be used in a for-loop to print the combinations one by one. The only change is to convert the tuple to a string, and can be done with `string.join`.

### Revised code

```
from itertools import combinations

S, k = input().split()
S_sorted = ''.join(sorted(S))
for i in range(1, int(k)+1):
    for c in combinations(S_sorted, i):
        print(''.join(c))
```

Comment: Thanks you for sharing this approach :)